# Регулярное выражение для выборки открывающего элемента по классу

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как написать регулярное выражение,которое из

```
<span class="mark"></span><div class="mark"></div>
```

выберет только

```
['<span class="mark">', '<div class="mark">']
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно пригодится тому, у кого регулярные выражения, не самая сильная сторона.

```js
let template = `<div id="someid" class="a b c" name="somename">
    <span class="b"></span>
</div>`;

const createRegExpWithSearchByClassName = className => new RegExp( `<(?!\\/)(.+?)(?=class=".*?${className}.*?")(.+?)>`, 'g' );

let regexp = createRegExpWithSearchByClassName( 'b' );
let result = template.match( regexp );

console.log( result );
```